Positional obstructive sleep apnea
How effective are mechanical positional sleep apnea treatments?  Vibratory positional treatments?  Do they approach CPAP in effectiveness?

Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in this meta post, this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.
